# How to validate specific hidden fileds in mvc using jquery validation plug in

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

In my form have multiple hidden fields when I try with

```
 $("#formid").data("validator").settings.ignore ="" it validate all the hidden filed.
```

try this also `$("#start-a-request-full-form").data("validator").settings.ignore = ':is("#hiddenfieldID1 ,#hiddenField2")):hidden';` did not work

My target is to validate only 2 hidden fields with some ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class name (say) `class="ignore"` to those hidden inputs you dont want validated and then use

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  ignore: ".ignore"
});
```

Comment: Thx  man save my day.. worked Just one more qn if i have different class already can i write class="hidden ignore".Did this also work @Stephen

Comment: Sure, no reason why not (but why do you have a class named hidden anyway - what would it do?)

Comment: rather than using input type=hidden i write input=text and class= hidden in css it has disply:none @Stephen

Comment: That's a strange way of doing it, but whatever works for you I guess :)

Comment: Is any possibility to write some think in those 2 field rather than editing all hidden fields :)

Comment: Not as far as I know, because the validator can only exclude controls (e.g. by input type or class name). There is nothing you can use to exclude `xyz` but then include `abc`.