# ASP MVC Razor - FormValidation - @Html.ValidationMessageFor - Editor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Validation working on all other elements i used sofar but validation-message for editor does not show up. ModelState has correct error-state, 
but no message can be seen on the form.

here is what i have:

MODEL:

```
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Diese Feld muss angegeben werden.")]
    [StringLength(8000,ErrorMessage = "Feld muss zwischen {2} und {1} Zeichen enthalten.", MinimumLength = 8)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Beschreibung")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

VIEW:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

this also does not work:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
```

when i do this in view:

```
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "test message")
```

it works - meaning, it shows "test message" - but i want the messages i defined in model...

---- here is some field that works as expected ----

MODEL:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dieses Feld muss angegeben werden.")]
 [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 2)]
 [Display(Name = "KeyWord")]
 public string Keyword { get; set; }
```

VIEW:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Keyword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Keyword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Keyword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

when field is empty and submit attempted, the required message is shown.
when field contains too-less or too many characters, and field is not in focus or submit is attempted, string-length message is shown ..
that's what i would like for the 2nd editor ...

----- end of working field -----

what am i doing wrong ?

thank you

---

SOLVED: 
  it was that "jQuery TE" was used to beautify the editor.

thank you  @Stephen Muecke and @Varun Vasishtha for pushing me there ;)

Comment: Are you saying that if you leave the textarea empty, that you do not get the error message?

Comment: basically yes, but it's also not showing when i put in 1 character ( just to have it not empty )

Comment: Well it should not show when you enter one character because it would then be valid :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke...`MinimumLength = 8` is set in model.

Comment: Didn't scroll across :)

Comment: The code you have shown works fine. I assume there is some other code causing the problem

Comment: @womd...just check the rendered html in console.

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gQCvsx) to prove its working with the code you have shown. Are you by any chance using a jquery plugin for the text area which hides the element (and therefore no validation will be done on the client)?

Comment: thanks @Stephen Muecke - your fiddle brought me closer ... it might be as you suggested that there is some jquery-plugin - since my "editor" - field - looks different thatn in the fiddle ... it has some WYSISYG-Controls --- have to check where this comes from ... 
thank you

Comment: Then you need to modify the `$.validator` (which by default does not validate hidden elements). Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840056/how-to-validate-specific-hidden-fileds-in-mvc-using-jquery-validation-plug-in/29840137#29840137) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379307/jquery-chosen-dropdown-validation-client-site-doesnt-work/26392882#26392882)

Comment: You should edit your question to indicate your using the plugin for the textarea, then this can be closed out as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a javascript error that is restricting jquery validation to work, try to debug using Firebug in Firefox

Comment: thank you, but could not find any issue .. will continue to look - i updated the question with a field that  works --- so generally validation is working ...

Comment: try with removing AllowEmptyStrings = false

Comment: ah, together with @Stephen Muecke fiddle i come closer ...as you said, there is some js restricting validation for this ... in my case a WYSIWYG editor ....
thank you

Comment: Cheers!!! .. mark it as an answer if you can

Comment: Its not a javascript error - its that hidden elements are not validated by default.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the last "test message":

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
```

See the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: thank you, but no message ether...

Comment: Are you using Unobtrusive Validation, with javascript or is on submit there is no errors?

Comment: think it uses Unobtrusive Validation, i'll update the question with some set of field that works as expexted ....